# Multiple tabs, Multiple while

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, session

I'm running multiple PHP scripts that have a while loop. This while insert and read from a MySQL database.

It is a long running process so it takes up to 2 hours.
What i need to do is to open the script in multiple tabs in the same browser.
When i do this and open the script in multiple tabs, I can't open over 6 tabs . any tab that is over 6 it just keeps loading and shows nothing.
When going to an other browser it works but when i reach the 6 tabs it does the same.

Code :

```
<?php
  ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
  ob_implicit_flush(TRUE);
  set_time_limit(0);

  $sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM old_Users Where age < 18";
  $content2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlselect);

  While($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($content2)){
    $Sql = "INSERT INTO New_Table_Users('first_name','last_name','ID') VALUES('".$row["firstname"]."','".$row["lastname"]."','".$row["idd"]."');
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  }
?>
```

The problem is not about the RAM, CPU because whenever i open a new browser it works fine, But when I try to open the 7'th tab it just keeps loading...
So to open 12 Tabs i would need to have 2 browsers each should have 6 tabs open...
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: 2 hours? why are you not running this as a background process? why are you using a browser at all? i guess the 6 tabs is for 6 threads? please dont do it this way

Comment: If it takes that long to run, then run it as a background task, not within the webbrowser

Comment: also the  above could be done in one query no loop required.

Comment: I Can't run this as a background proccess because i need to see outputs. This is just a part of the script. it's missing an echo.

Comment: `INSERT INTO New_Table_Users ('first_name','last_name','ID')
SELECT  ('first_name','last_name','ID')
FROM   old_Users Where age < 18`

Comment: are you honestly sitting there watching it for 2 hours? can't you just log some output?

Comment: @Dagon, Yes i know that this can be done in one query. But i do have other scripts that uses a while loop and i really want to know what is going on here. I want to solve this problem if possible.

Comment: If you run the job from the command line, you can send the output to a log and simply tail that if you want to monitor it, or view it later at your leisure

Answer (score 0):

Dagon solution is the best but in case you need to process stuff in PHP and still be able to insert at a fast pace.

Using PDO (sorry dont like mysqli neither while) to do it faster than you breath. This will insert all data with very few queries (batches). It could even be with only one insert for it all.

**WARNING:** this technique is  fast but know your limits . It needs RAM or lower the number of simultaneous inserts.

Depending on the size of what you are inserting, limit the number of simultaneous inserts, depending on your RAM capacity. With 3 params , as you have (very very few), insert batches of 10000 sounds reasonable. Try various to see how your database and server handles it.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1); 
set_time_limit(0);

$table = 'New_Table_Users'; // inserted table name
$nb_max_insert = 10000; // number of maximum simultaneous insert
$age=18;// param age

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM old_Users Where age < ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $age, PDO::PARAM_INT); // prepare binder

try {
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump('error main');
}

if (count($result) !== 0) {

    $data = array();// extract needed data , yes you are using * in you query. mheeeee
    foreach ($result as $key => $el) {
        $row['first_name'] = $el['first_name'];
        $row['last_name'] = $el['last_name'];
        $row['ID'] = $el['ID'];
        array_push($data, $row);
    }

    $batches = array_chunk($data, $nb_max_insert);// split data into batches

    foreach ($batches as $key => $batch) {

        foreach ($batch as $d) {
            $question_marks[] = '(' . query_placeholders('?', sizeof($d)) . ')'; // create question_marks sequence for PDO
            $insert_values = array_merge($insert_values, array_values($d));// what to insert
        } 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (" . implode(",", array_keys($row)) . ") VALUES " . implode(',', $question_marks); //concat the query
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        try {
            $stmt->execute($insert_values);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            var_dump('error batch');
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I am using it to insert millions of rows into huge tables, across PHP7 pthreads (12 CPU x 20 cores) reaching the limit of the server with 1024 async connections with 3X 12Go RAID X4 SSD 1to. So I guess it should work for you too....